# Add a custom action in ShareActionProvider menu

Tags: android

Putting a `ShareActioProvider` in an action bar and setting an intent on it is an easy way to share content on Android.

I would like to add my own action (e.g. "Add Bookmark", "Save for Later" etc) in the drop down menu that appears on screen when you tap on the share menu item. Is this possible?

I thought about creating an intent filter to capture the share intent within the app but I don't know if this would be the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

The ShareActionProvider should deal exclusively with share actions. Android provides ways for adding other custom actions (buttons) on the ActionBar.

The [example provided on the official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) shows how to add a 'search' button. Thus, you can add your bookmark/save buttons alongside the share action provider one.

Additional actions can be moved to a spill-over button if there's too many of them to fit in the action bar.

Comment: To clarify, what I want to do is to "insert" a custom non-share action in the Android share sheet. I could separate it out into another button/menu but I want to know if its possible to customize the Android share sheet in this way.

Comment: You could only if the ShareActionProvider allowed setting an adapter on it. Such an adapter would be a custom ArrayList of your custom actions (views), along with the standard list of share platforms offered by the ShareIntent `Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)`
That would be painstaking to achieve.

IMO, hiding custom actions in the share button obfuscates the functionality & thus would confuse your users